# How to read WCF ClientSection from separate config

Tags: c#, wcf

I have my client section in a separate config file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="ep1 />
        <endpoint name="ep2 />
        <endpoint name="ep3 />
    </client>
</configuration>
```

*I have tried two of versions config file (The second being the one above). The original version being without the `xml` and `configuration` tags. When those tags are not present (which I think is correct), I instead get an error trying to open the file with the OpenMappedExeConfiguration method.*

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : 
Configuration file Web_ServiceModel_Client.config does not have root 
<configuration> tag ([PATH]\Web_ServiceModel_Client.config line 8)
```

I would like to read the client section, however, it always is null. My attempt

```
string configPath = Path.Combine(Config.AppPath, "Web_ServiceModel_Client.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configPath };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ClientSection cs1 = config.Sections["client"] as ClientSection;
ClientSection cs2 = config.GetSection("client") as ClientSection;
```

Both cs1 and cs2 are null.

How can i read the client section so I may cycle through the endpoints?

```
ChannelEndpointElement selectedEndpoint = null;
foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in cs1.Endpoints)
{
    if (endpoint.Name == "MyServiceName")
    {
        selectedEndpoint = endpoint;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Additional**
`config.Sections("client") is DefaultSection`. So when I cast it to `ClientSection`, it is null. Why is it a `DefaultSection` and why can't i cast it to `ClientSection`?

When i try the following

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup group = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
var client = group.Client;

//client.EndPoints.Count == 0 !!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a main configuration file like the following:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.serviceModel>
    ...
    <client configSource="Web_ServiceModel_Client.config" />      
    ...
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And that you're asking about howto read the value from the external configuration file (**Web_ServiceModel_Client.config**). There's two issue with your code:

1. You're opening the wrong configuration file. Instead of opening the external config files, you should open the main configuration file (the one with `<configuration/>` tag):

   ```
   string configPath = Path.Combine(Config.AppPath, "Main_Configuration_File.config");
   ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configPath };
   Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   ```
2. Your'e using the wrong section name. I assume `ClientSection` is [`System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ClientSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.clientsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so based on its configuration path you should pass `system.serviceModel/client` as sectionName:

   ```
   ClientSection cs2 = config.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
   ```